# Are these lemmas on divisibility correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have this fraction: 
$\frac{25×10}{25+x}$ 
I was wondering what are the possible values of x that will make the above fraction an integer? x is a positive integer. A quick calculation shows that if x is 0, 25, 100 or 225 then the above fraction will be an integer. Therefore the following two lemmas seem to be correct:

Lemma 1: If $\frac{25+x}{25}$ is a divisor of 10 then the above fraction will be an integer.

Lemma 2: x cannot take any value below 25 except 0.

I was wondering whether we can generalize these two lemmas as follows:

$\frac{a×b}{a+x}$

Lemma 3: if $\frac{a+x}{x}$ is a divisor of b then the above fraction becomes an integer.
N:B take $\frac{a+x}{x}$ to be a rational number.

Lemma 4: x cannot take any value below a except 0.

I am interested in the proof that lemma 3 and 4 are true (or maybe even false).
This probably sounds intuitively true but what is the actual proof for the general case? I am unable to come up with the proof.

Comment: If $a=2, b=3, x=1$ then $x<a, x\ne 0$ and $\frac{ab}{a+x}$ is an integer. So lemma 4 is false.

Comment: @markvs yes lemma 4 is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for lemma 3:

$$\frac{ab}{a+x} = \frac{b}{\frac{a+x}{a}}$$

Comment: Alright, that is quite clever. That solves lemma 3. What about lemma 4?

Comment: What if $(a+x)/a$ is not an integer?

Comment: Lemma 4 is false (Lemma 3 does not make sense).

Comment: @markvs but the OP is saying it is a divisor, so x has to be set to make it an integer I think

Comment: @markvs I am not sure you have understood the question.

Comment: @Tortar It is a divisor in what ring? The ring of rational numbers has lots of numbers which divide each other. As I said, Lemma 3 does not make sense,

Comment: You seem to not understand that the question about lemma 3 does not make sense. Lemma 4 is false, see my comment above.

Comment: @Mathguru: In order to say that $u$ is a divisor of $v$, you need to specify the ring or a magma (you need a binary operation) where $u,v$ "live". Usually in such problems the ring is the ring of integers. But in your case $(a+x)/a$ is rarely an integer, but a general rational number. In the ring of rationals any two non-zero elements divide each other, so your condition in Lemma 3 does not make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135544/discussion-between-markvs-and-mathguru).